# Better hand rig?

Tags: animation, rigging

So I have a hand, but I need to adjust the rig somehow to make the base of the finger properly deform,

If you grab your hand into a fist, you will see the creases between your fingers make an X, there is an extra amount of loose skin that folds downwards, I'm trying to achieve that
[image]

currently it looks like this:[image]

As you can see the knuckle deforms improperly, I've tried fixing it by including a second bone to control the joint, but they haven't been successful

My goal is something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Dv74NFSnnI

Comment: maybe you should put a bone into this part of the hand?

Comment: I did try, but my attempts didn't work, making that happen seems pretty difficult in 3d, that bulge is due to how the joint is constructed (there's some cartilage there so the tendons don't get pinched) If I move the joints to deform that part, it will interfere with the knuckles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a corrective shape key, driven by the rotational difference of the two nearby bones, so that when the angle gets close to 90 degrees, the shape key gets fully activated.